# How to sent the unsent mails

Tags: asp.net, smtp, smtpclient, mail-server

Work on vs2010 ,asp.net C#.Recently I work on smtp server.Using the smtp server I need to send mail, I already successfully done this job . To send mail I use the bellow **syntax**.

```
public string PostEmail(string mailSubject, string mailBody)
{

    string deliveryStatusCode = "Ok";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailSubject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(gConfig.EmailTo))
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(gConfig.EmailTo);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(gConfig.EmailTo);
        msg.Subject = mailSubject;
        msg.Body = mailBody;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(gConfig.SmtpHost, gConfig.SmtpPort);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(gConfig.SmtpCredentials, gConfig.SmtpPassword);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;


        try
        {
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (SmtpException smptpEx)
        {
            deliveryStatusCode = smptpEx.Message;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        deliveryStatusCode = "Invalid or null value entry.";
    }

    return deliveryStatusCode;
}
```

.Now I face one problem,for some reason some mail cannot be sent ,those unsent mail need to be sent ,How to send those unsent mail,Is there any mechanism in smtp to perform this job or there is some way to solve this issue.Thanks in advance .If have any query plz ask.

Comment: i don't know why people marked negatively,i think above question is not like a child candy,plz any one tell me .why it's a bad question?

Comment: You say they can't be sent, but that isn't clear. Is your code throwing an error? Does the message leave your system but never arrive? There are so many hops in the emails trip, that narrowing it down to your small piece of example code is impossible.

Comment: The question is far from clear. As Chase says, "can't be sent", what does that mean? Did you get an exception? Do you get a reply (in which case they *did* get sent, they just weren't received by the correct recipient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pickup directory, if the smpt server is down the mail is not send. When it comes online, it will read the files in the directory and starts sending the emails.

Answer (score 0):

Your .NET code simply takes a message, generates and email, and sends it off to the SMTP server. It's up to the SMTP server to resend any messages that are unsent.

You can do what @peer said, and instead of sending an SMTP message, simply drop a generated file in the SMTP pickup directory, however this requires your .NET code to have access to the SMTP pickup directory.

Another option might be to store the email object (either in memory, or serialized on disk) and if the `send` throws an error, retry later.

Ultimately however, you really need to find out why the email isn't going through in the first place. It's often a configuration issue that can be mitigated with a little investigation. Look into network connectivity, SMTP Server Uptime, and most importantly.. authentication.

As I said in my comment, the generated email makes a great many hops before finally landing in the end users inbox. Without a little more details as to what *is* erroring, we can only throw darts and hope that one of them lands.

Good luck
Chase